# Does Flutter app generates too much cache?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a flutter app and using basic widgets like BottomNavigationBar, ListBuilder, intro_slider(additional plugin) etc. When I swipe through slides, click on tabs, open pages using Navigator.pushNamed the app is generating cache. Is this because I am launching the app in a development environment or this will be the same for the final build.

Trying to find a better way for cache management that will not create an unnecessary heap of cache in users devices.

Thanks

Comment: `"or this will be the same for the final build"` - what stops you from checking that by yourself?

Comment: "is generating cache" what cache are you talking about?